# Trying to set GOPATH and GOROOT in AWS EC2 user data, but it is not working

Tags: go, amazon-ec2

I am trying to set up GOPATH GOROOT in my `AWS EC2 Ubuntu 20.04` user data, but it never worked, every time I connect to the `AWS EC2` and view the log in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` it always says
`go: not found`, but if I key in the echo part it will work.
I am trying to set up multiple EC2 with this basis, so I can't key in every instance myself.
The CloudFormation yaml user data part is below:

```
UserData:
        Fn::Base64: |
          #!/bin/bash
          wget https://dl.google.com/go/go1.14.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz
          tar -C /usr/local -zxvf go1.14.4.linux-amd64.tar.gz
          mkdir -p ~/go/{bin,pkg,src}
          echo 'export GOPATH=$HOME/go' >> ~/.bashrc
          echo 'export GOROOT=/usr/local/go' >> ~/.bashrc
          echo 'export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin:$GOROOT/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
          echo 'export GO111MODULE=auto' >> ~/.bashrc
          source ~/.bashrc
          apt -y update
          apt -y install mongodb wget git
          systemctl start mongodb
          apt -y install git gcc cmake autoconf libtool pkg-config libmnl-dev libyaml-dev
          go get -u github.com/sirupsen/logrus
          cd ~
          git clone --recursive https://github.com/williamlin0504/free5gcWithOCF.git
          cd free5gcWithOCF
          make
```

And here is the error inside `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`
[Error while user data runs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqhkX.png)
Is there anyone is familiar with this, please I need some help~

Comment: Please look in ``/var/log/user-data.log`` and add some errors to your question

Comment: There is neither need to set GOPATH nor GOROOT. If the `go` command is not found then because you PATH is wrong. Just use the full path / usr/local/go/bin/go.

Comment: @Vorsprung I've checked through, but I didn't see `/var/log/user-data.log` just the running process of user data as `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`, and I've just add it to my question, thank you.

Comment: @Volker So you mean I export the `PATH=/usr/local/go/bin/go` into .bashrc? Thank you.

Comment: No, of course not, that is just plain nonsense. /usr/local/go/bin/go is not a path to a folder. Either `export PATH="$PATH:PATH=/usr/local/go/bin"` or call the go tool via its full path `/usr/local/go/bin/go`. It really is _simple_. Just try to understand what heppens if you type `go <RET>` in your shell.

Answer (score 0):

In your error message, in the Makefile at line 30 there is a program bin/amf being used

This program appears to be a shell script with a problem in line 1

The nature of the problem is "go: not found"

If you have the bare word "go" in line 1 of the shell script and the path cannot find it then this is what will happen

Probably you need to alter the last line of your userdata shell script to say

```
PATH=/usr/local/go/bin:$PATH make
```

I know you have a `source` command earlier in the script that is supposed to set this up but it doesn't do what you think it does